# Passing a stand alone script in a plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a few stand alone scripts and I am in the process of making a toolbar from them.

Most of my script have arguments like this :

```
##Points=vector
##Distance= number 2000
...
```

Those lines make a parameter window appear before the processing is done. This is the standard interface for stand-alone scripts.

Yet, is it possible to find a way to just link them in the plugins or do I have to make a new gui. Every button should be linked to one script.

Right now, the button have been done this way :

```
def initGui(self):
    """Create the menu entries and toolbar icons inside the QGIS GUI."""

    self.add_action(
        ':/plugins/Concentration/param.png',
        text=self.tr(u'Param'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())

    self.add_action(
        ':/plugins/Concentration/group.png',
        text=self.tr(u'Algorithmes de groupement'),
        callback=self.run,
        parent=self.iface.mainWindow())
...
```

So if I could just find away aroud the `callback=self.run` to run a script just like I do in qgis(like `callback = Param.py`), it will save me the time to remake an interface for those scripts.